# Disable zend form element Enter keypress event

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

Does anyone know how to disable the Enter keypress event of a zend element text input control? When a user presses Enter on a form element it tries to post, which I want to disable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this Should solve your problem

```
$textField = new Zend_Form_Element_Text("text");
$textField->setAttrib('onkeypress', 'nullifyEnterKey();');
function nullifyEnterKey(e)
{
    var key;      
    if(window.event)
          key = window.event.keyCode; //IE
     else
          key = e.which; //firefox      
     return (key != 13);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is something you'll need to do client side (i.e. with Javascript). With Dojo it would be something like:

```
dojo.connect(dojo.byId('FIELDID'), 'onkeydown', function(event){
    if (event.keyCode == dojo.keys.ENTER) {
        dojo.stopEvent(event);
    }
});
```

replace 'FIELDID' with the ID of the text field you want to hook this into. You could combine this with a `dojo.query` call if you want to apply it to everything in the form.

jQuery and the other JS frameworks will have an equivalent.